# Spread of malaria from an infected person

Tags: pathology, parasitology

If a person is infected with malaria, how can that person be a part of spreading malaria? As in, if a female anopheles mosquito sucks blood out of that infected individual, how is it possible that malarial schizonts will be only sucked by the mosquito and not pure blood? The point is, out of such a huge volume of blood, how can only malarial parasites enter the suckling mosquito?

Answer (score 7):

With humans infected with malaria, the parasite load in the blood can be quite high. It ranges from [10 to 10<sup>8</sup> *Plasmodium falciparum* parasites per ml](http://jcm.asm.org/content/38/11/4072.full) .

When a female *Anopheles* mosquito bites an infected human, they take in infected blood, not just the parasite. They take in [a few micro liters of blood](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16007951), which in usually enough to get themselves infected, and the next time they bite a human (about one week later), the infection is spread.

You can learn more at the [CDC malaria FAQ](http://www.cdc.gov/malaria/about/faqs.html) and their overview of the [malaria transmission cycle](http://www.cdc.gov/malaria/about/biology/).